# c# assembly binding with wpf application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, .net-assembly

I would like to binding a dll file from a further out folder with my app.

For example:

> *File structures:*
>
> -Important.dll
>
> -Folder
>
> - MyApplication.exe

I need something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="../" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

But it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

We solved that in the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
        <runtime>
                <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
                        <dependentAssembly>
                                <assemblyIdentity name="Important" publicKeyToken="1234567890abcdef"/>
                                <codeBase version="1.2.3.4" href="../OtherFolder/Important.dll"/>
                        </dependentAssembly>
                </assemblyBinding>
        </runtime>
</configuration>
```